# Contador de like com JS/Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho varios cards em uma pagina e cada card tem uma opção de curtida igual do facebook, quando clico na imagem o contador aumenta 1, porem esta contando em todos os cards e não somente no que eu cliquei e tambem cada vez que eu clico sobe um gostaria que se o usuário clicar uma vez ele `aumenta um` se clicar de novo ele `diminui um` igual do facebook `like` `dislike`.

Segue um exemplo do que tenho hoje

```js
var count = 0;

$(".click").click(function() {
  count++;
  $(".click").css('opacity', "0.7");
  $(".like").html(count + "Curtidas");
  $(this).off(event);
});
```

```css
.click {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class='click'>Clique</li>
    <li class='like'>0 curtidas</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class='click'>Clique</li>
    <li class='like'>0 curtidas</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class='click'>Clique</li>
    <li class='like'>0 curtidas</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Quanto tempo você já gastou fazendo isso?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa é importante isso? Se sim, não gastei muito tempo não na vdd no momento não é algo tão serio mass como comecei a mexer gostaria de saber se é possível só com JS fazer isso.

Comment: É possível sim fazer só com JS.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa obrigado, respondeu uma das minhas dúvidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No evento `click` utilize o `this` para obter apenas o elemento que foi clicado.
Para manipular o item que está logo abaixo, no caso o `li` com a classe `like` utilize o `next`. Da maneira que você fez `$(".like")` estava manipulando o valor para todos os itens com essa classe.

```
$(this).next().html(count + " Curtidas");
```

Também para "salvar" a quantidade de curtidas em cada item, utilize o atributo [data-*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp), com isso poderá recuperar e incrementar o total de likes.

```
<li class='click' data-like-count="0">Clique</li>
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando:

```js
$(".click").on('click', function() {
  var count = parseInt($(this).attr("data-like-count"));
  count++;
  $(this).css('opacity', "0.7");
  $(this).next().html(count + " Curtidas");
  $(this).off(event);
  $(this).attr("data-like-count", count);
});
```

```css
.click {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class='click' data-like-count="0">Clique</li>
    <li class='like'>0 curtidas</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class='click' data-like-count="0">Clique</li>
    <li class='like'>0 curtidas</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li class='click' data-like-count="0">Clique</li>
    <li class='like'>0 curtidas</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado era isso mesmo, acho que deixando assim fica mais facil pro back-end dar continuidade depois.  Mas ficou show vlww ! 

Obs: Alias ultima coisa, é possível em vez de aumentar o like se o usuario clicar de novo ele retirar o like?  Ou isso é so via back-end vlww

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está perdendo a referência para o botão que está clicando. Isso aqui `$(".like").html(count + "Curtidas");` vai pegar **todos** os elementos com a classe `.like`.

Para seu código funcionar vai ter que usar o `$(this)` como referência. E para o efeito de voltar a 0 basta fazer um if.

Segue o exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.like').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next('.likes').find('span').text(function() {
            if (parseInt($(this).text()) === 0) {
                return parseInt($(this).text() + 1);
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt architecto aut eligendi saepe nihil, officiis officia, est! Deserunt cupiditate voluptate necessitatibus. Aspernatur, vitae earum atque hic maxime facere sequi sint!</p>
      <button class="like">Curtir</button>
      <span class="likes"><span>0</span> curtidas</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

@Edit:

O problema é que você precisa salvar isso em algum banco de dados, não vai conseguir fazer só com JS. Ao atualizar a página vai perder todos os dados.

O mais coerente é fazer uma validação no back-end e trabalhar com requisições AJAX para inserir esses dados.

Lá você verifica a identidade do usuário e se ele já votou, caso já tenha votado retorna 0 para incrementar, do contrário incrementa mais 1.

Comment: Legal entendi, queria deixar o menos trabalhoso possível pro pessoal do back-end, vc acha que desse jeito que ta facilita para eles? Obrigado.

Comment: Não, esse código não tem contato nenhum com o back-end, é perigoso tratar dados no front-end. O seu código deveria fazer uma requisição para o back, e lá os dados são tratados e retornados para o front..